# Help with Corrupt version of IE8 on WinXPsp3

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, internet-explorer, windows-update, sp3

I've upgrade from IE6 to 7 to 8 and back down and back up, but still have critical issues in IE such as

- cannot see any version info in "about internet explorer"
- cannot run windows update
- cannot load SharePoint pages (and other pages using ActiveX or IE-specific dhtml)

I've also re-installed sp3, but still no luck.
Also, also - I've changed security settings to be most permissive.

Next step is blowing it all away and starting with windows7. Short of that, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool has worked for me in the past.  Not always, but more often than not.  Saved a lot of grief.

[FixIE Tool](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-internet-explorer-with-fix-ie-utility)

Comment: Glad it worked.  It has saved me a lot of grief on more than one occasion.